# jquery animation imperfection in multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

demo http://www.bootply.com/gyEJYEzFei

Obviously the animate() non-async caused them cannot be trigger at the same time, but I have no idea why when mouseleave there is a overlapping issue at the bottom row. I tried css with transition and now with animate() still cannot perfect the animation.

part of the code

```
$('.hoverExpand').mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

  var getIndexOfTarget = $this.closest('.product-panel').index();

  if(getIndexOfTarget % 2 == 0){ //check target if is even 
    $('.product-panel').filter(function(i) {
      return i > 2 && i % 2 == 1
    }).animate({'margin-top':"-=100px",
            "transition":"all 0.2s linear"
          });
  }else{
    $('.product-panel').filter(function(i) {
      return i > 1 && i % 2 == 0;
    }).animate({'margin-top':"-=100px",
            "transition":"all 0.2s linear"
          });
  }


    if (!$this.hasClass('on')) {
        $this.addClass('on');
        $this.find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
            "margin-top": "200px"
        }, "fast",function(){



        });
        $this.find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
            opacity: 1,
                'transition': 'opacity 0.45s ease 0.15s'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `transition` property is not animatable. Set it in your CSS or use `.css({transition: "all 0.2s linear"})` somewhere in your chain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to mix jquery and css transitions. I would pick one or another.
If your structure would be something like:

1. Here's a simple example with only CSS (and a simplified HTML structure):

   **http://jsfiddle.net/mk1etnc8/1/**
2. If you want to use jquery animation, you could do something like this;

   ```
   $('.product').hover(
       function(){ $(this).child('.product-lower').slideDown();},
       function(){ $(this).child('.product-lower').slideUp();});
   ```

   I didn't test this code at all, but perhaps you get the point.

Hope this helps!